# Wordpress blog page keeps on loading

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

i have a website www.thecreativeverge.com. When i click on blog link, page keeps on loading forever. upon inspection, blog page does not populate from section heading. Any help will be highly appreciated
PS: newbie in wordpress

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? See: [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) for more details.

Comment: Look in the Network Requests tab in your browser too to see if anything is stuck on loading a resource. You may also have an infinite loop not finishing somewhere perhaps.

Comment: nothing in network request tab brother

Comment: there should be something wrong with your preloader script.